# Window resizing doesn't change value java

Tags: java, swing, resize, window, jframe

I'm trying to have dynamic resizing for my program and for that I need to know the window size at all times. It's working up until when I added the getBounds() method and I used println() to output the changing size of the window. However it doesn't seem to be registering the changing window with the method and I was wondering how, here's the code I use to get the window it will print the original size but the number doesn't change as the window does.`org.frame.getBounds().getX()` and the same for Y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get notified by any Swing component of layout changes by attaching a ComponentListener (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html).

The way Swing intends you to make a dynamic layout is by using LayoutManager's (a LayoutManager will adjust components automatically using the constraints provided for each component). It sounds like you are trying to reinvent the wheel. Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html for an introduction to LayoutManagers.